# How test a Rxjs empty operater using Jest

Tags: typescript, rxjs, jestjs, nestjs

I was trying to write some tests in a personal NestJS sandbox project.

```js
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  private todos: Todo[] = [
    { id: 1, text: 'Learn Typescript', isCompleted: false },
    { id: 2, text: 'Learn Nestjs', isCompleted: false },
    { id: 3, text: 'Use Mongodb in Nestjs', isCompleted: false },
  ];

  findAll(): Observable<Todo> {
    return from(this.todos);
  }

  findById(id: number): Observable<Todo> {
    const foundTodos: Todo[] = this.todos.filter(d => d.id == id);
    console.log("foundTodos:" + JSON.stringify(foundTodos));
    if (foundTodos.length > 0) {
      return of(foundTodos[0]);
    } else {
      return empty();
    }
  }

  //other methods
}
```

And I tried to test the `empty()` is called, how to archive this in jest test using a `expect`?

```js
  it('findById with none-existing id should return empty', done => {
    service.findById(100).subscribe({
      next: data => console.log('data:', data),
      error: err => console.log('error', err),
      complete: done(),
    });
  });
```

**Update:** I've also found a working solution for myself.

1. Add `toArray()` to `pipe()` to convert the stream to array.
2. Assert the `data.length` equals 0 in the `next` handler in the subscriber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test easily for completion you can use the built in [rxjs marble test](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/internal-marble-tests):

```
describe('foo', () => {
  let testScheduler: TestScheduler;

  beforeEach(() => {
    testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
  })

  it('should test for completion', () => {
    testScheduler.run(helpers => {
      const { expectObservable } = helpers;

      expectObservable(empty()).toBe('|');
    })
  })
})
```

The `|` sign marks a completion.

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `done()` in `complete` handler. Calling `done()` will trigger the method immediately. You probably wanted to use just `done` so it'll be invoked by the handler itself.

Otherwise the way you're testing `empty()` is correct. Maybe you could fail the test on any `next` or `error` notification as well.

```
it('findById with none-existing id should return empty', done => {
  service.findById(100).subscribe({
    next: data => console.log('data:', data),
    error: err => console.log('error', err),
    complete: done,
  });
});
```

Comment: but I am not sure where to add assertions, the `expect`(if added) in the `next` and `error` never called.

Comment: If you want to make sure it's never called make eg. `next` handler with `broken = true` and then in `complete` you can `expect(broken).toBe(false)`.